# Trying to figure out a solution to this question

Tags: sql, oracle

Eliminating duplicate answers and mismatch in SQL

So the problem states that I need to find the transactions that happened each day and there is a mismatch between my answer on the correct answer and I don't know why!

this is a Short database description "Recycling firm"

The firm owns several buy-back centers for the collection of recyclable materials. Each of them receives funds to be paid to the recyclables suppliers. Data on funds received are recorded in the table
Income_o(point, date, inc)
The primary key is (point, date), where the point holds the identifier of the buy-back center, and the date corresponds to the calendar date the funds were received. The date column doesn’t include the time part, thus, money (inc) arrives no more than once a day for each center. Information on payments to the recyclables suppliers is held in the table
Outcome_o(point, date, out)
In this table, the primary key (point, date) ensures each buy-back center reports about payments (out) no more than once a day, too.
For the case income and expenditure may occur more than once a day, another database schema with tables having a primary key consisting of the single column code is used:
Income(code, point, date, inc)
Outcome(code, point, date, out)
Here, the date column doesn’t include the time part, either.

and The question is :
Under the assumption that receipts of money (inc) and payouts (out) can be registered any number of times a day for each collection point [i.e. the code column is the primary key], display a table with one corresponding row for each operating date of each collection point.
Result set: point, date, total payout per day (out), total money intake per day (inc).
Missing values are considered to be NULL.

```
SELECT Income.point, Income."date", SUM("out"), SUM(inc)
FROM Income left JOIN 
 Outcome ON Income.point = Outcome.point AND
 Income."date" = Outcome."date" 

GROUP BY Income.point, Income."date"
UNION 
SELECT Outcome.point, Outcome."date", SUM("out"), SUM(inc)
FROM Outcome left JOIN 
 Income ON Income.point = Outcome.point AND
 Income."date" = Outcome."date" 

GROUP BY Outcome.point, Outcome."date";
```

Comment: might get a better response if you make some create table statements and data for Income and Outcome, and your expected results from the sample data. you can head over to http://sqlfiddle.com/ and choose oracle as the drop down

Comment: Also, every question on SO is *"Trying to figure out a solution to this question"*. Please, choose a better title.

Comment: sorry im new to SO and this is my first time, it will be better next time.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you have a bit of a Cartesian join by not including CODE as part of your join criteria. I think the following query should suit your needs:

```sql
WITH calendar AS
(
  SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE)-(LEVEL-1) AS DT
  FROM DUAL
  CONNECT BY LEVEL < 30
)
SELECT d.pnt AS "POINT",
       c.dt AS "DATE",
       d.outcome_total,
       d.income_total
FROM calendar c
LEFT JOIN (SELECT nvl(inc.pnt, outc.pnt) AS PNT,
                  nvl(inc.dt, outc.dt) AS DT,
                  outc.amt AS OUTCOME_TOTAL,
                  inc.amt AS INCOME_TOTAL
           FROM (SELECT i.pnt, i.dt, sum(i.inc) AS AMT
                 FROM income i
                 GROUP BY i.pnt, i.dt) inc
           FULL JOIN (SELECT o.pnt, o.dt, sum(o.inc) AS AMT
                      FROM outcome o
                      GROUP BY o.pnt, o.dt) outc ON inc.pnt = outc.pnt AND inc.dt = outc.dt) d ON c.dt = d.dt;
```

I added the calendar table to account for the case where there was neither an income nor an outcome on a given day.  However, if you don't need that, the query within the LEFT JOIN should be just fine.

N.B.: With the addition of the calendar WITH clause, this query will currently only show results from the last month(-ish).  If you need longer, adjust the 30 day window.

Comment: The cartesian join I mentioned will only cause you problems on days where there are multiple incomes and multiple outcomes.  So most of your data probably looks fine.  It is just those busy days which will be off.

Comment: @afbigdad et al.: I fixed some column name issues and a missing comma, it should compile now.  Let me know if that fixed your issue.

Comment: it gives me this error Code: (933) ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended